# Android Bitmap contour

Tags: android, contour

I'm trying to draw the contour of my drawable,
I tried to use Blur, as in this page:
[How to make glow effect around a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334341/how-to-make-glow-effect-around-a-bitmap)
Its effect is not what I want,
I want a "solid" contour, 
not blurred.

anyone knows how?

Comment: Have you tried Blur.SOLID, here is an example: http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/07/2d-graphics-with-effects_11.html

Comment: I have, and it made my image all white, as you can see in page you suggested. "Blur.SOLID" doesn't create a contour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no outline type filter or mask that I can find, while blur and shadow mask are not very strong. Hence you could create your own effect by using color filter and scale. This example would create a red contour

```
ColorFilter filter;
filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(0xFFFF0000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);         

paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
paint.setColorFilter(filter);

canvas.save();
canvas.scale(1.1f, 1.1f,imageCenterX , imageCenterY);
canvas.drawBitmap(image, imageX, imageY, paint);
canvas.restore();

canvas.drawBitmap(image, imageX, imageY, null);
```

It is fast enough for a game frame animation, I've tested it.