# How to add outer glow to bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm looking for to create something like this: http://imm.io/Bcco

The outer glow + the white space around the image. I've already seen [How to make glow effect around a bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334341/how-to-make-glow-effect-around-a-bitmap). But there was no conclusive answer provided there.

I'm willing to consider a hackish solution if that's the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a 9-patch png that is a box with an outer shadow around it with the content marks (right and bottom) be inside the white part. Then set that to the background of whatever element you want to add the shadow to. Here is one that I made just now that you can use or will give you and idea of what to do.

If you are unfamiliar with [9-patch images read about them here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

[image: outer shadow box]

*Note: You'll need to save it as something.9.png*

you can drop it into draw9patch and adjust the sides if you need more or less whitespace.