# Android - How to make an icon glow on touch?

Tags: android, icons, touch, glow

How to get this blue glow effect over an icon? Is there any quick way of doing it? I really don't want to use photoshop for this effect.

Any help would be really appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You have to make use of statelistdrawables in which you will define the blue effect.Please visit the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501716/android-how-to-create-a-statelistdrawable-programmatically

or you can visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to generate the glow programatically, here's how you can do. My advice, generate it just once at the beggining of your activity, then create a StateListDrawable using it, as said in the comment :

```
    // An added margin to the initial image
    int margin = 24;
    int halfMargin = margin / 2;

    // the glow radius
    int glowRadius = 16;

    // the glow color
    int glowColor = Color.rgb(0, 192, 255);

    // The original image to use
    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    // extract the alpha from the source image
    Bitmap alpha = src.extractAlpha();

    // The output bitmap (with the icon + glow)
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth() + margin,
            src.getHeight() + margin, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // The canvas to paint on the image
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(glowColor);

    // outer glow
    paint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(glowRadius, Blur.OUTER));
    canvas.drawBitmap(alpha, halfMargin, halfMargin, paint);

    // original icon
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, halfMargin, halfMargin, null);

    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bmpImg)).setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: I really like the way you explained the stuff using comments. Thanks.